# How can I make a class property array be a heterogeneous array of a generic type?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

Here's what I want. I'm writing a very simple [event dispatcher](https://gist.github.com/Evertt/339d0eda49018c2f1b8b) (click that link to see my code). It was working fine when I only had the `listen()` and the `fire()` method. This is how you could use it:

```
struct UserHasBirthday: Event {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let events = TestDispatcher()
events.listen {
    (event: UserHasBirthday) in
    print("Happy birthday \(event.name)!")
}
events.fire( UserHasBirthday(name: "John Doe") )
```

That's all well and good, but now I wanted to add the feature that you could push events to a queue and then later fire them all at once. That's why I added the push and flush methods.

Now the problem is that in the `flush()` method I need to be able to downcast the generic `Event` type to the specific event type that was given. Otherwise the `fire()` method doesn't work.

So I thought, maybe I could save the type information in the same array as the event itself. As you can see I tried to do that with a tuple. Unfortunately it doesn't work like that.

I think that if I could find a way to make the variable `pushedEvents` accept a generic type like so: `var pushedEvents = Array<E: Event>()` then it could work. But the only way I know to do that is to assign that generic to the whole class like so: `class TestDispatcher<E: Event> { }`, but then every instance of that class can only be used for one specific type of event and I definitely don't want that.

Does anybody know some kind of way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/4c37cf/how_can_i_make_a_class_property_array_be_a/d1exgtl) gave me the solution by using a so-called type-erasure pattern (I didn't know about that pattern).

I edited his code to meet my needs more and this is what I have now:

```
public protocol Event {}

public protocol ErasedListener {
    func matches(eventType: Event.Type) -> Bool
    func dispatchIfMatches(event: Event)
}

public struct Listener<T: Event>: ErasedListener {
    let dispatch: T -> Void

    public func matches(eventType: Event.Type) -> Bool {
        return matches(String(eventType))
    }

    func matches(eventType: String) -> Bool {
        return eventType == String(T.self)
    }

    public func dispatchIfMatches(event: Event) {
        if matches(String(event.dynamicType)) {
            dispatch(event as! T)
        }
    }
}

public protocol Dispatcher {
    func listen<E: Event>(listener: E -> Void)
    func fire(event: Event)
    func queue<E: Event>(event: E)
    func flushQueueOf<E: Event>(eventType: E.Type)
    func flushQueue()
    func forgetListenersFor<E: Event>(event: E.Type)
    func emptyQueueOf<E: Event>(eventType: E.Type)
    func emptyQueue()
}

public class MyDispatcher: Dispatcher {
    var listeners = [ErasedListener]()
    var queuedEvents = [Event]()

    public init() {}

    public func listen<E: Event>(listener: E -> Void) {
        let concreteListener = Listener(dispatch: listener)

        listeners.append(concreteListener as ErasedListener)
    }

    public func fire(event: Event) {
        for listener in listeners {
            listener.dispatchIfMatches(event)
        }
    }

    public func queue<E: Event>(event: E) {
        queuedEvents.append(event)
    }

    public func flushQueue() {
        for event in queuedEvents {
            fire(event)
        }
        emptyQueue()
    }

    public func emptyQueue() {
        queuedEvents = []
    }

    public func flushQueueOf<E: Event>(eventType: E.Type) {
        for event in queuedEvents where String(event.dynamicType) == String(eventType) {
            fire(event)
        }
        emptyQueueOf(eventType)
    }

    public func forgetListenersFor<E: Event>(eventType: E.Type) {
        listeners = listeners.filter { !$0.matches(eventType) }
    }

    public func emptyQueueOf<E: Event>(eventType: E.Type) {
        queuedEvents = queuedEvents.filter { String($0.dynamicType) != String(eventType) }
    }
}
```

## Example usage

```
struct UserDied: Event {
    var name: String
}

class UserWasBorn: Event {
    let year: Int

    init(year: Int) {
        self.year = year
    }
}

// you can use both classes and structs as events as you can see

let daveDied = UserDied(name: "Dave")
let bartWasBorn = UserWasBorn(year: 2000)

var events = MyDispatcher()

events.listen {
    (event: UserDied) in

    print(event.name)
}

events.listen {
    (event: UserWasBorn) in

    print(event.year)
}

events.queue(daveDied)
events.queue(UserWasBorn(year: 1990))
events.queue(UserWasBorn(year: 2013))
events.queue(UserDied(name: "Evert"))

// nothing is fired yet, do whatever you need to do first

events.flushQueue()
/* 
    This prints:
    Dave
    1990
    2013
    Evert
*/

// You could also have flushed just one type of event, like so:
events.flushQueueOf(UserDied)
// This would've printed Dave and Evert,
// but not the year-numbers of the other events
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Swift doesn't allow type conversion to metatypes.

One workaround is to include all types that conform to `Event` (at least those you will use in your `Dispatcher`) in a switch case in the `flush()` function of your `TestDispatcher` class. It isn't as versatile as the functionality I believe you're looking for, and [as you've shown with your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242803/4573247), type erasure is the way to here. I'll leave my original answer intact however, as it explains why your original approach of attempting to cast to metatypes didn't work.

```
public protocol Event {}

public enum Listener<E: Event> {
    public typealias T = E -> ()
}

public protocol Dispatcher {
    func listen<E: Event>(listener: Listener<E>.T)
    func fire<E: Event>(event: E)
    func push<E: Event>(event: E)
    func flush()
}
```

//

```
public class TestDispatcher: Dispatcher {
    var listeners = [String:[Any]]()
    var pushedEvents = [Event]()

    public init() {}

    public func listen<E: Event>(listener: Listener<E>.T) {
        var listeners = self.listeners[String(E.self)] ?? []
        listeners += [listener] as [Any]
        self.listeners[String(E.self)] = listeners
    }

    public func fire<E: Event>(event: E) {
        listeners[String(E.self)]?.forEach {
            let f = $0 as! Listener<E>.T
            f(event)
        }
    }

    public func push<E: Event>(event: E) {
        pushedEvents = pushedEvents + [event]
    }

    /* Include a switch case over all types conforming to Event ... */
    public func flush() {
        for event in pushedEvents {
            switch event {
            case let ev as UserHasBirthday: fire(ev)
            case let ev as UserWonTheLottery: fire(ev)
            case _: print("Unknown event type.")
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
struct UserHasBirthday: Event {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct UserWonTheLottery: Event {
    let name: String
    let amount: Int

    init(name: String, amount: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }
}

let events = TestDispatcher()
events.listen {
    (event: UserHasBirthday) in
    print("Happy birthday \(event.name)!")
}
events.listen {
    (event: UserWonTheLottery) in
    print("Congratulations \(event.name) for winning \(event.amount)!")
}

events.push(UserHasBirthday(name: "John Doe"))
events.push(UserHasBirthday(name: "Jane Doe"))
events.push(UserWonTheLottery(name: "Jane Doe", amount: 42000))

events.flush()
/* Happy birthday John Doe!
   Happy birthday Jane Doe!
   Congratulations Jane Doe for winning 42000! */
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's not going to cut it for me, because an event dispatcher is a bit useless to me if it's limited to only a few events. In that case I'd rather not have the push / flush feature.

I upvoted you, because maybe there's really no other way around it. But I haven't marked your answer as accepted yet, because I'm still clinging on to some hope that this can be done in some hacky way. Just like I used an enum to create a generic typealias.

Comment: @Evert I can understand that, and I also I think you should keep this question open a day or so, maybe someone else can give more valuable hacky-input (I used the word "_possibly_ it doesn't get better than this" above as there might actually be some structure wrapper workaround that I haven't thought about :).

Comment: in case you're interested, I've posted a working answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36242803/1498652).

Comment: @Evert: nice, using type erasure did actually briefly float by in my mind yesterday, but I'm not very well-versed with the concept, so I dropped that. Also, each additional method used by the erased type tend to generate some amounts of boilerplate bode, but in this case, I'd say this is probably the best solution, nice work (to you and reddit guy :). If possible, add a usage example (as is: only the listener framework) to you answer whereafter I believe you should accept it as answering your question.

Comment: It says "You can accept your answer tomorrow". So I'll do that if I remember.

Comment: @Evert Final note: it's quite neat to include default implementations of the methods blueprinted the `Dispatcher` protocol as extensions to this protocol, as has been done by the reddit user Danappelxx [in his original answer to you](https://gist.github.com/Danappelxx/a53f642e4011035d9090). This way, [`MyDispatcher` needn't be so bloated (see gist)](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/c624e058beb0ab9aeb52) as it really has no need to implement its own implementations of the blueprinted `Dispatcher` methods.

Comment: I didn't do that because I wanted to keep the `events` and `listeners` variables of `MyDispatcher` private. I don't want outsiders to be able to meddle with those variables directly.